# Proving for polynomial: $P (1)=0\implies|P'(1)|\leq \frac{\deg(P)}{2}\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

I wonder if it is true that any polynomial $P(z):\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ with $P (1)=0$ satisfies
$$|P'(1)|\leq \frac{\deg(P)}{2}\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|, $$ where the maximum is taken over the unit circle.

At least numerically it seems to be the case and the extremizer seems to be $P(z)=z^n-1$.

If $\deg(P)=1$, then $P(z)=z-1$. Hence, $P'(1)=1$ and $\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|=2$.

Comment: What about the polynomial $P(z)=(z-1)(z+1)^{n-1}?$

Comment: If $P(z)=(z-1)(z+1)^{n-1}$, then $|P'(1)|=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @RaulHindov I like this question, at the moment it has a few close votes. Can you kindly answer the following questions and place them in the question post : what is the source of this question? What is your background in complex analysis? Are you able to verify the cases $n=1,n=2$ with proof? If so , provide the proof.

Comment: This is being done with the future of your question in mind. As much as we'd like the question to be answered, it does not seem to come from a prior motivation, and furthermore there are no indicators as to what level you are at, so that any answerer will know what level their answer (or any potential argument) needs to be tailored towards.

Comment: @RaulHindov Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: $$P(X)=(X-1)(X+1)^{n-1}$$ Let $$z_1=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$ such that $$\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|=|P(z_1)|=|\cos\theta+i\sin\theta-1||\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+1|^{n-1}\\=|-2\sin^2\theta/2+i\sin\theta/2\cos\theta/2||2\cos^2\theta/2+i\sin\theta/2\cos\theta/2|^{n-1}=2^n\sin\theta/2(\cos\theta/2)^{n-1}$$ and $|P'(1)|=2^{n-1}$

Comment: [Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)#Bernstein's_inequality) could be useful.

Comment: Also, if you look at the article I mentioned above, there is a paragraph starting with "Paul Erdős conjectured that ...". I don't expect an easy proof as a result.

Comment: @rtybase: Bernstein's theorem came into my mind as well. The question is how to utilize $P(1) = 0$ to get the additional factor $1/2$. – The Paul Erdős conjecture is proved here: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574519-4/. It does not look *too* complicated, but I don't know if it helps to solve the problem given here.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you! The Lemma 2 in the Aziz-Mohammad paper implies our inequality. I think the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjectured inequality is true, and a consequence of Lemma 2 in

- [Abdul Aziz and Q. G. Mohammad, Simple proof of a theorem of Erdős and Lax, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1980), 119-122](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574519-4/).

> Lemma 2. If $P(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then
> $$|P'(z)| + |nP(z) - zP'(z)| \le n \max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|$$
> for $|z| = 1.$

In our case is $P(1) = 0$, so that
$$
2|P'(1)| \le n \max_{|z|=1}|P(z)| \, .
$$

Comment: There is even stronger result at the end of the paper. Look at the Corollary!

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

An inductive approach seems very promising to me:

It is true for $n=1$.

Now, let $n\in\mathbb N$, and let $P_{n+1}:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be a polynomial of degree $n+1$ with $P_{n+1}(1)=0$. We can write $$P_{n+1}(z)=P_n(z) (z+c)$$ for some $c\in\mathbb C$ where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ satisfying $P_n(1)=0$. We have

$$P_{n+1}'(1)=P_n'(1)(1+c)+P_n(1)=P_n'(1)(1+c).$$

So by the inductive assumption,

$$\lvert P_{n+1}'(1)\rvert\le\frac n2\lvert 1+c\rvert\max_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \lvert P_n(z)\rvert.$$

If we could thus prove that

$$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{n\lvert1+c\rvert\max_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\lvert P_n(z)\rvert\le(n+1)\max_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\left(\lvert P_n(z)\rvert\lvert z+c\rvert\right)}$$

for every $c\in\mathbb C$ and polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$ with $P_n(1)=0$, we would be done. I do not know, however, whether the highlighted statement is true and if yes, how to prove it.