# Proving for polynomial $P(z)= \sum_{j=0}^{d}a_jz^j \in \mathbb{C}[z]$: $\frac{2}{d+1} \sum_{j=0}^{d} |a_j| \leq \max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

The aim is to find a lower bound for the maximum of polynomial $(z-1)P(z)$ on the unit circle in terms of the moduli of the coefficients of $P(z)$ and we conjecture that:
$$
\frac{2}{d+1} \sum_{j=0}^{d} |a_j| \leq \max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)|.
$$
It clearly holds for some simple cases like $P(z)=a_dz^d$ and $P(z)=1+z^d$. The equality holds for example to $P(z)=1+z+z^2+...+z^d$.

Note that there is an easily found upper bound:
$$
\max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)| \leq |a_0|+\sum_{j=1}^{d}|a_j-a_{j-1}|+|a_d| \leq 2\sum_{j=0}^{d}|a_j|, 
$$
whereas the desired lower bound seems harder to establish.

If the coefficients of $P(z)$ are unimodular, ie $|a_j|=1$ for all $j$, then we can form $P^{*}(z)=\prod_{j=1}^{d} \left(z-\frac{\alpha_j}{|\alpha_j|} \right)$ from $P(z)=a_d\prod_{j=1}^{d} \left(z-\alpha_j \right)$ by sliding the zeros of $P(z)$ to the unit circle. Then we have by Sergei Konyagin and Vsevolod Lev (in their 2003 paper, "On the maximum value of polynomials"), that $|P^{*}(z)|\leq |P(z)|$ on the unit circle. Among the polynomials that have all their zeros on the unit circle the smallest possible maximum on the unit circle is 2 (by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64099/the-maximum-of-a-polynomial-on-the-unit-circle ) and so we have for the case $|a_j|=1$ for all $j$,
$$
\frac{2}{d+1} \sum_{j=0}^{d} |a_j| \leq \max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)|.
$$

Comment: Where does the problem come from? – It reminds me of your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091539/42969, which can possibly be applied to $Q(z) = (1-z)P(z)$.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes the questions are related. If the current inequality is true then it would imply the previous one.

Comment: Do you *know* that this lower bound is true, or is that a conjecture?

Comment: @MartinR: It is just a conjecture based on numerical simulations.

Comment: I can show that $\frac{2}{d+1}| \sum_{j=0}^{d} a_j| \leq \max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)|$, but that is of course a weaker result. My *guess* would be that the conjecture is wrong, but I haven't found a counterexample so far.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, that is exactly the result in the previous question you referred to. It looks like that the extremizer is in both cases $P(z)=1+z+z^2+...z^n$ with $\max|z-1||P(z)|=2$.

Comment: @MartinR You write you can show that $\frac{2}{d+1}| \sum_{j=0}^{d} a_j| \leq \max_{|z|=1}|z-1||P(z)|$. Could you share that proof? - it may be a starting point / reference for solving the claim of this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas: It follows from applying https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091539/42969 to $Q(z) = (1-z)P(z)$, since $Q'(1) = P(1) = \sum_{j=0}^{d} a_j|$. I am not sure if that helps, my feeling is that this here is a stronger statement than the referenced one, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Andreas: The other result is applied to $Q$ which has the degree $d+1$.